# How to use enums as a value alias in Rust?

Tags: rust

In the below code, how to use `Interval::Minute` as `60`?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Interval {
    Minute = 60,
    Hour = 3600,
    Day = 86400,
}


fn main() {
    let interval = 120;
    let minute = Interval::Minute;
    println!("Number of minutes: {:?}", interval/minute);
}
```

That is, how to use it as an alias for the underlying value?

Comment: @Shepmaster This question is different as the desired solution was to use `interval::MINUTE` vs `Interval::Minute as i32`

Comment: Your literal question is "how to use an enum as a value". That's what the duplicate is. You happened to learn about an alternate solution you like and that's great, but that solution has *nothing to do with enums*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast it to an integer type:

```
let minute = Interval::Minute as i32;
```

Another option is to use `const`s within a module, depending on what you're trying to do:

```
mod interval {
    pub const MINUTE: i32 = 60;
}

fn main() {
    let interval = 120;
    let minute = interval::MINUTE;
    println!("Number of minutes: {:?}", interval/minute);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it also true that `interval::MINUTE` adds no overhead (zero cost abstraction) compared to using an int value of `60`?

Comment: @Greg what abstraction? `interval::MINUTE` **is an integer**.

Comment: @Greg Constants (`const`) are inlined in-place by the compiler wherever they're used, at compile time, so they have no fixed address in memory like a local variable would. I don't know if that's what you're asking.

Comment: That clears things up, thank you